# GCM - Rarely receiving topic messages

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) and GCM for push notifications on iOS and Android. The last three weeks I've had no problems what so ever. However out of nowhere it stopped functioning normally. I receive about 1/20 messages sent.

I'm using GCM's topic messaging. When I send a message I get a successful response.

```
Object {message_id: <MESSAGE_ID>}
```

But I only rarely seem to receive the message.

If I send a message directly to a device(registration_token) the message is received properly.

I've tested with both a jquery ajax request as with a request from a C# back-end. Both resulting in the same.

My jQuery test script:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "key=<AUTH_KEY>",
            "Content-type": 'application/json'
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({
            to: "/topics/" + topics,
            priority: 'high',
            content_available: true,
            notification: {
                body: msg,
                title: "Test",
                sound: "bubble.wav"
            },
            data: {
                soundname: "bubble.wav",
                test: "test"
            }
        })
    }).done(function (attr) {
        console.log('done');
        console.log(attr);
    }).error(function (err) {
        console.log('err');
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Tested on both android and iOS. Same results for both.

Comment: This is not only a phonegap problem. Happens on Xamarin as well (since this morning).

Comment: I'm getting the feeling the problem lies with GCM, but can't find anything like a internal server status. Just received a notification I sent about 2 hours ago on 1 out of 2 devices.

Comment: We're facing the same problem (since this morning as well). Everything seems to go like it should be, but no luck.

Comment: Same here. Since this morning. No changes were made...

Comment: I seem to be slowly receiving all the messages i sent today. I received about 30 notifications in the past hour. Hopefully Google's got this fixed by tomorrow. Been trying to use FCM in the meantime but seem to be running into the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like they finally acknowledged the outage: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Cloud%20Messaging/16002

Comment: Good, gonna test it out right now. Was looking for such a status page but couldn't find it. Thanks!